# error with dbus and gesettings inside docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, gsettings

after using the command `RUN apt-get install -y dbus` building and then running the container I try to change system proxy with the command `gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy.https host 'proxy-adress'` but I get the output `failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process ?dbus-launch? (No such file or directory)`. I assume that dbus was not installed so I check the path with `whereis dbus` but the output is empty. is it uninstalling itself?.

Comment: What program will the container eventually run?  Can you provide a [mcve], for example including your Dockerfile?  (Graphical applications are particularly hard to run in Docker and have trouble interacting with the rest of the Linux desktop environment, and you might find it easier to run a GNOME application without involving Docker.)